# Ruby on Rails: what's the best rails plugin choice for facebook connect? and how to access the facebook user information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, plugins

I was wondering if there is any good choice of rails plugin for facebook connect?
Currently, I am using authlogic for authentication in my app. However, I would like to allow users to login with their facebook account as well, which allows me to access some of their facebook information in my app. (I am trying to achieve similar things that stackoverflow is doing -- being able to register/login using their existing facebook account)

I googled it and found authlogic_facebook_connect, but many other people have suggested that this plugin is outdated and has bugs. I was wondering what other options have people been using?

another thing that I am struggling on is that once facebook connection has been established, how do I access facebook user's information? I can't seem to find a tutorial on this....

Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything like this I find RubyForge (www.rubyforge.com) the best place to go. They have a project on there that may be suitable for what you need:

FaceBooker
http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/

I have read good reviews about it, but haven't tried it personally as of yet.

Comment: thank you very much. facebooker gem does seem to be under more active support than authlogic_facebook_connect. I was able to find some tutorials about it as well.